# {SOAP UI} Is there any way to call one test case step from project tear down

Tags: javascript, soap, groovy, soapui

As part of my project I need to call some test case (groovy step) once project is exccuted .
I need to know how can we achieve this... From project tear down in soap UI

Since test runner is not scope so I am struggling to proceed further.

Ideas will be very helpful.

Comment: you may create another testCase that contains your groovy step, maybe in a 'tools' testSuite, and do a distant call to this step. Use it as a method. You could also build a custom library and set your groovy step as a lib method (slightly different and it may not be trivial if you try to use classes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution for my question:

```
def project = context.testCase.testSuite.project
def testSuite = project.getTestSuiteByName("TestSuiteName");
def testCase = testSuite.getTestCaseByName("TestCaseName");
runner = testCase.run(new com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToObjectMap(), false);
```

this code can work from anywhere in the soap ui.

any how Thanks for the support...

Answer (score 1):

If this is really a TestCase that should be run at the end of a Project, you may simply create it as the last TestCase. The disadvantage of that is that your extra testcase will be a part of the test report.

You may also add it as a TestCase, which you then DISABLE, to prevent it from being executed normally as a part of the project. You then add a teardown script on your project. This could be something like:

```
runner.project.getTestSuiteByName("TestSuite Name").getTestCaseByName("TestCase Name").getTestStepByName("Groovy Script Name").run(runner,context)
```

But be aware, that using this solution, this script will only be run, when you run the entire project.

Comment: Thanks Steen for your response.   I'm accepting this answer

Comment: Hi Steen ,Did you tested this code? i tried today alone but unfortunately it was not working as expected and shows error 
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.run() is applicable for argument types: Possible solutions: run(com.eviware.soapui.model.testsuite.TestCaseRunner, com.eviware.soapui.model.testsuite.TestCaseRunContext)

Answer (score 0):

Project, Test Suite and Test Case all have a tear down script and all have runner passed into them.

Comment: How do we run the cases using runner??

Comment: I've tried building an example, but it doesn't seem possible (nor advised according to SmartBear forums) to run a test step from a Project tear down.  Setup and Tear-downs are typically used for resetting your environment before and after a test.

Comment: It's ok Chris.. thanks for your support... I also tried some apporaches but doesn't worked.